# web service(jax-ws) and weblogic

Tags: weblogic

i have web service(cxf integated with spring(jax-ws)) project which it was deployed on Weblogic(12.1.1).
Another project as client was deployed same application server in another machine.

My problem is that at least 23 second of time for sending info from server to client.(this time is more long),but this time very fast when request is called by Soap Ui.
how can i config weblogic for improvement this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching a lot finally i found solution of my problem.
JaxWSProxyFactoryBean is object of cxf client to communicate with cxf server.
This Object have a property is named Bus,if this property not set in config cxf client,performance wont be better